# jQuery: Scroll position becomes locked after scroll to bottom animation

Tags: javascript, jquery

Using the code below, I am cloning elements on click, then scrolling to the bottom of the page.

This seems to work, however, the scroll bar becomes locked and scrolling upwards is restricted.

**How do I allow scrolling upwards again after the scroll to the bottom animation?**

Cloning on click:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".showdiv1").click(function() {
    $(".div1").first().clone(true).appendTo("section").fadeIn("500");
```

scrolling to bottom:

```
$('html, body').animate({scrollTop:$(document).height()}, 3000);
        return false;
      });
```

https://jsfiddle.net/vanderhurk/uzsx4agr/32/

(click "clone div1" or "clone div2" to see)

Comment: You have added 3 seconds animation in this code ` $('html, body').animate({scrollTop:$(document).height()}, 3000);` that's why your are seeing  a delay.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is about timing 3000 millisecond delay is very long to scrolling

You need to apply `slow` or `fast` place of 3000 delay

[Check this example code on codepan](https://codepen.io/saAction/pen/PyabEp)

Comment: This is correct. Slow is still quite fast, is there a way to slow the animation without causing this delay?

Comment: Either you can remove it, let system decided its speed, or you need to find out correct millisecond gap, But any number is not appropriate because more you create clones it will become more faster because of document height increase.